# How can I convert this VBS script to Bash?

Tags: bash, vbscript

I have this code in VBS that I need to rebuild in Bash. This is a snippet of a larger script that I have to convert. Can someone please help me with this?

I have read a lot of documentation on Bash in the last two days that I have been working on the larger script but am still not sure how to go about doing this. My coworker/trainer essentially handed me this and told me to use Google to learn Bash in order to do this. I feel it's also important to note that I am not familar with VBScript either.

```
Function Build_Param_Array()
    Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set ReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Param_List.txt")
    While Not ReadFile.AtEndOfStream
        thisline = ReadFile.ReadLine
        Pcount = Pcount + 1
        ReDim preserve arrParam(Pcount)
        If Not Right(thisline,1) = "|" Then thisline = thisline & "|"
        arrParam(Pcount) = thisline
    Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a vbs guru, but winging it for a general guess, it looks like it reads Param_List.txt, makes sure each line ends with a pipe character, then pushes it onto an array (arrParam).

```
typeset -a arrParam       # declare an array
while read l              # read each line from stdin into l
do arrParam+=("${l%|}|")  # push the line onto the array, assuring a |
done < Param_List.txt     # put the file on the loop's stdin
```

`$l` is the line read. `${l%|}` is the line read, with any pipe as the last character removed; thus `"${l%|}|"` explicitly removes a pipe *if* there was one, then adds one whether or not one was removed.